# React setState push new object to array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-state

I have a state containing an array of objects. I'd like to push new objects to that array with setState. I'm not really sure how to go about it. Would appreciate any help.

code:

```
interface permissions {
    guild_id: number,
    role_id:number,
    command_id: number
}

export default function Permissions(){

const [permissions, setPermissions] = useState<permissions[]>([]);

const handleSwitchChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        if(event.target.checked){
            // add to permissions
            const addedPermission = { 
                guild_id: 907366719130054800,
                role_id: role,
                command_id: parseInt(event.target.id)
            }
            
            //This should also keep the current array of objects
            setPermissions([addedPermission])
        }else{
            
        }
    };
//api calls to get the data
}
```

A friend recommended using a "triple dot(...)" notation in the setPermissions. This however gave an error that a spread argument must either have a tuple type. Does anyone know what he's talking about too?

Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: `setPermissions(prev => [...prev, addedPermission])`

Comment: `setPermissions(permissions => [...permissions, addedPermission])`

`...` => this is called the **spread operator** which copies the old structure (here permissions array) and create a new structure with that value

This also works in case of objects in JS.

Comment: I'm looking at the documentation now. I tried `setPermissions(...permissions, [addedPermissions])` earlier. This makes so much sense now. I'll answer the question when the cooldown is over. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the two kind people pointed out in the comments a spread operator should be used like:

`setPermissions(permissions => [...permissions, addedPermissions])`

The link to the spread operator documentation can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)